# Odd sized dictionary

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

**Question:**
Let $\sigma$ be a signature that has only equality as a relation in it.
Prove that there doesn't exist a statement $\phi$ s.t it's valid in M $\iff$ $|D^M|$ is odd.

**My problem:**
I think the statement is false... but the textbook asks me to prove it.
If I pick M s.t. $D^M=${1,2,3} and $\phi= \exists x \exists y (x=y)$ then I found a statement like the one I'm supposed to show doesn't exist...
Where is my problem?

Comment: Have you learned the compactness theorem? And Lowenheim's theorem, the one saying that if a sentence has an infinite model then it has a countable model? Using those two theorems you can show that, if $\phi$ is true in every even finite model, then $\phi$ is true in some countably infinite model. Likewise you can show that if $\not\phi$ holds in every odd finite model, then $\neg\phi$ holds in some countably infinite model. Since all countably infinite models in the signature with only $=$ are isomorphic, it follows that $\phi$ and $\neg\phi$ hold in one and the same model, which is absurd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the statement $\phi$ should be a statement which classifies this property for any finite model. For instance if $D^M=\{1,2,3,4\}$ then $\mathcal{M}\models \exists x\exists y (x=y)$. Thus your formula $\phi$ does not satisfy $\mathcal{M}\models \phi$ if and only if $|D^\mathcal{M}|$ is odd, for all finite structures $\mathcal{M}$.

One of the easier ways to prove this theorem, if you got the tools, is to use an Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse game. Just take two structures $M$ and $N$ of size $n$ and $n+1$ and show that we can play $n$ step between them (which is easy since there are no relations). Thus we may conclude that $M$ and $N$ satisfies the same formulas of quantifier rank at most $n$, and thus if $\phi$ exist, it can't have quantifier rank $n$, for any arbitrary number $n.$

Comment: Why does M doesn't satisfy $\phi$ on the 4 sized D you proposed? I can always take x=y no matter if D is even or odd, can't I?

Comment: Sorry, M satisfy $\phi$. The point is that as an even model satisfy $\phi$, thus $\phi$ is not such that $M$ satisfy $\phi$ if and only if $|D^M|$ is odd. So the formula does not work.